# Path to a text file in a complex hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, path

Inside my solution, I have a folder called "Server". This folder contains a project called "InvestmentAdvisory", which contains the folders Report/Languages/. Inside Languages are a class "Translation", and a CSV file. The class is supposed to load the CSV file.

The namespace of the class "Translation" is like:

```
 "Server.Modules.InvestmentAdvisory.Report.Languages"
```

After the application is built, the CSV file ends up in:

```
 MyApplication\Main\Source\InvestmentAdvisory.Services.Implementation\bin\Debug\Report\Languages\
```

How do I find the relative path to the CSV from the inside of my Translation class?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i'm miss understanding but if you need the directory of your application you can get the path by using

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your assembly/exe outputs will be in

MyApplication\Main\Source\InvestmentAdvisory.Services.Implementation\bin\Debug

You can use the relative path:

```
.\Report\Languages\CsvFileName.csv
```

The easiest approach would be to keep the csv file in the output folder.

1. Add the csv to project
2. Select the csv file and in properties window
   (Press F4 to open the window if not present), set Copy To Output
   Directory (Always/If Newer).

Then you would not need a path as long as the assembly/exe are all in the same folder i.e. output folder.

Comment: The CSV file is actually copied to "MyApplication\Main\Source\InvestmentAdvisory\bin\Debug\Report\Languages". And the relative path you suggested produces the "wrong" path:
"MyApplication\Main\Source\Server.Deploy.MyApplication.Web\Report\Languages\ReportExpress_Languages.csv"

Comment: Sorry! Is it a web application?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") will get you the root of the web server where your website/application is present. You should be able to map the path from there?

Comment: I just noticed the CSV file is also copied in the location you assumed it would. I'm sorry I led you wrong, but the client side is a web application. Here I'm on the server side, a WCF server.

Comment: Give this a try then (may need a bit editing):
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + "\Report\Languages\CsvFileName.csv"